# why is the scope function called multiple times?

Tags: angularjs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
 </head>

<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="personCtrl">

 First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstName"><br>
 Last Name: <input type="text" ng-model="lastName"><br>
<br>
Full Name: {{fullName()}}

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('personCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.firstName = "John";
$scope.lastName = "Doe";
$scope.fullName = function() {
 console.log("inside");
    return $scope.firstName + " " + $scope.lastName;
}
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

the console log value shows inside three times .. i am new to angularjs so please be kind enough to let me know why this happens

Comment: If you ouput `console.log($scope.firstName + " " + $scope.lastName)` you might see more. Please show us the output, too

Comment: John Doe
John Doe
John Doe

Comment: @MarcHarry linked question is about digest loop limit and not scope change lifetime.

Comment: @RameshKhadka you can extract fullName behavor into filter, this way it'll be called only once per dependant value change.

Comment: @Klaster_1 The post covers both the watchers calling the function multiple times and also angulars digest loop limit. And what the other question asks is addressing the same as this post, the watchers calling the function multiple times.

Comment: While I agree that the linked possible-dup answers this question(Specifically, Stewie's answer), the *accepted answer* there doesn't seem to address the actual question..

Comment: can anyone tell me what i can do so that the function is called only once

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The scope function is called every time angular emits a scope change event. This is built in to fake an ES6 function called `Object.watch`.

So it doesn't really matter that it gets called several times, this is just Angular's way of checking for changes ;)

Comment: @Pepijn - I don't agree with you saying "it doesn't matter", infact it does matter because the function body is been reevaluated with every $digest cycle, which might have a knock on effect on the performance of your application. If I was you, I would pre-calculate whatever function  is trying to do and then simply bind the return value to scope property as a variable/object i.e. `$scope.value = precalculatedValue;` and then do `ng-bind="value" | {{value}}"` this approach will only call it once!

Answer (score 1):

Because $scope.fullName is a function which will get called every time firstName or lastName changes, and inside this function you have a console.log call which logs the fullName on every change.

Comment: It will actually be called on every digest, not just when `firstName` or `lastName` change.

Comment: @Sacho Actually you're right